# LED indicators for 2 Positive voltages and 1 Negative

Tags: voltage, led, negative, indicator

I have a seemingly simple question but I am getting stumped.

I have a power supply providing +12v +5v GND and -12v. I would like to have an LED for each input voltage showing that they are working correctly. The '+' Voltages are all simple, However, I am having trouble with the -12v input.

Any help or a point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem you are having with the -12V input?  It might help us help you if you showed a schematic of your circuit.

Comment: I think the problem was with the -12v input on my cheapo power supply. So flipping the led was, in fact, working in that it was not illuminating because there was no - input at all. The irony.

Comment: Perfect, so your LED correctly told you that the -12V was missing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is turn the LED around.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frUPLM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>